# How to select the name field and description field and fill the fields and need to click on next button

Tags: jquery

[how can we fill those fields using jquery selectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYEnj.png)

the html code is as bellow

```html
<div class="col-xs-4 h100">
  <div class="title">What do you want to name your application as ?</div>
  <div class="help-text tMargin10">The name you provide here will be the application name used. Typically, it is the project name or repo name.</div>
  <div class="row applicationName">
    <form id="create-application-form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name your Application </label>
        <i class="fa fa-question-circle" title="The name you provide here will be the application name. Typically, it is the project name or repo name. Application name must begin with an alphabet and recommend not to use consecutive _, -, whitespaces. Ex - My_app_name, my app name, my-app-name are allowed. Please avoid names like my___app___name, my app name, or my-----app----name"></i>
        <span class="mandatory" title="Mandatory">*</span>
        <input class="form-control behavior-validate required" data-validation="[{"rule":"application_name"}]" minlength="4" maxlength="21" name="name" value="" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Description</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="description"></textarea>
        <div class="help-text">This description will be displayed to users who may want to join your team. (Optional)</div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="viewActions text-right">
    <button class="btn btn-primary continue next hasError" type="button" title="Mandatory field missing" disabled="disabled">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help me using `jQuery` selectors.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would be good to show the script you've been working on.

Comment: Please elaborate further by showing what script have you written?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/s4mz5kf8/2/

```js
var data = {name:"", description: ""}
$('input[name="name"], textarea[name="description"]').focusout(function(){
  data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
  
  if(data.name != "" && data.description != ""){
    console.log(data);
    $('.next').removeAttr('disabled').click();
  } else {
    $('.next').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-4 h100">
  <div class="title">What do you want to name your application as ?</div>
  <div class="help-text tMargin10">The name you provide here will be the application name used. Typically, it is the project name or repo name.</div>
  <div class="row applicationName">
    <form id="create-application-form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name your Application </label>
        <i class="fa fa-question-circle" title="The name you provide here will be the application name. Typically, it is the project name or repo name. Application name must begin with an alphabet and recommend not to use consecutive _, -, whitespaces. Ex - My_app_name, my app name, my-app-name are allowed. Please avoid names like my___app___name, my app name, or my-----app----name"></i>
        <span class="mandatory" title="Mandatory">*</span>
        <input class="form-control behavior-validate required" data-validation="[{"rule":"application_name"}]" minlength="4" maxlength="21" name="name" value="" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Description</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="description"></textarea>
        <div class="help-text">This description will be displayed to users who may want to join your team. (Optional)</div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="viewActions text-right">
    <button class="btn btn-primary continue next hasError" type="button" title="Mandatory field missing" disabled="disabled">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm checking for both the `input textbox`, if any of the `input textbox` is empty then next `button` will be disabled.

Hope this will help you.